# Why is the added content in the HashMap only request life

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I am implementing an Android app which has checkboxlist where the user can selects routes, then a response with data `latitude, longitude, route, direction, id` is being received from the server.

Is there any explanation for this behaviour in the adding part (else block) when I add a new route to my bus table with the same selected one, the new added route id is being recognized and the else block is being entered afterward **the marker is being added to the HashMap** but is not being displayed on the map.

Additionally when the new Response reaches the method again I noticed that **the last added marker with the new id is not** in the HashMap and it just contains the elements of the first request also when the request is over and the new added element stays in the HashMap for the request Life!

**Code:**

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap map;
    HashMap<Integer, Marker> markerMap = new HashMap<Integer, Marker>();
    Marker marker = null;

    private void gotoLocation(int id, double lat, double lng,
            String route_direct) {
        // check = false;

        final float zoom = 11;
        LatLng ll = null;

        if (markerMap.containsKey(id)) {
            //Update block.
            // Update the location.

            // To figure out which ones was not updated.
            idList.add(id);

            marker = markerMap.get(id);
            // Remove from the map fragment.
            marker.remove();
            // Remove from the HashMap tp add the new one.
            markerMap.remove(id);

            ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            if (lat != 0 && lng != 0 && !route_direct.isEmpty()) {
                MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(route_direct).position(ll).visible(true);
                marker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);
                markerMap.put(id, marker);

                CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll,
                        zoom);
                map.moveCamera(update);
            }

        } else {
            //Add block.
            // Add the marker on the map in the case it does not exist in the
            // HashMap before.
            ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            if (lat != 0 && lng != 0 && !route_direct.isEmpty()) {
                MarkerOptions markerOpt = new MarkerOptions()
                        .title(route_direct).position(ll).visible(true);
                marker = map.addMarker(markerOpt);
                //Here when I add a new record to my table then it is being added to the HashMap but this block is being always entered since the new added one just stays for the request life and is not as the added content of the first request.
                markerMap.put(id, marker);

                CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll,
                        zoom);
                map.moveCamera(update);
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Seems like your instance of `Map` class (which extends from `FragmentActivity`) is created several times, so your `markerMap` is *reinitialized*.

Comment: @TheTime It's difficult tell what could be the issue but remember that if you insert a value into a map for an existing key, only the value is replaced. The old key is retained.

Comment: @CKing: also in my case the table id is the key and it is unique also I am adding a new key and marker to the Map.